# need help reading file contents into an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

I want to be able to do $> ./program file.txt 8
and then read the 8 values inside file.txt into an array

heres the code I have right now but it doesn't work

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream file;
    int size;
    int arr[size],val;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cin>>val;
        arr[i] = val ;
    }
```

Comment: `int size;` then `int arr[size],val;` is a bug. In `c++` size must be specified at compile time.

Comment: @drescherjm And even if `size` was initialized, variable-length arrays are non-standard.

Comment: Lookup the usage of std::vector<int>

Comment: Also `./program file.txt 8` means you need to handle command line arguments and you are completely ignoring them.

Comment: You also read the values from cin, and not from any file.

Comment: I see in your previous question you were told to ask a different question. You probably should have updated the code since then with the changes to handle the command line parameters.

Comment: I honestly am really lost with what and where needs to be updated and all that good stuff. I get the cin part at the end doesn't work with what im trying to do now @Ian4264

Comment: I don't understand how to handle the command line arguments and then have the file.txt be read in an array in a form similar to `int arr[size],val; `

Comment: The integer argc is the number of arguments, while argv is an array of character strings of that number. Usually the first argument is the name of the program itself so if you pass no arguments, argc will be 1 and argv[0] will be "program". You will need to check that argc is 3 then get the file name from argv[1] and the size from argv[2] which will also means you have to read an integer from that string. After that you can open the file for reading, and read the integers into a vector (don't try reading into a non-standard variable length array)

Comment: Command line arguments are delivered to your app via the parameters of main ... argc, and argv.  There are many examples of code available.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to read some values off of a text file. You can do that like so:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::string textArray[8]; // array to store the data

    std::fstream textFile; // creating a file object

    textFile.open("text_file.txt", std::ios_base::in); // creating and opening a text file

    if (textFile.is_open()) // check to see if file opened sucessfully
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 8; ++a)
        {
            getline(textFile, textArray[a]); // using getline to get the values of the file
            std::cout << textArray[a] << "\n";
        }

        textFile.close(); // closing the files after we're done using it
    }
}
```

As you can see, we opened a file, and used `getline()` to read the contents of that fine and store it in an array.